# SharePoint 2010 Taxonomy Control Multi Value

Tags: sharepoint-2010, metadata, managed

I´m using the Taxonomy Control in my Webpart for selecting documents from a document library using MMD. I tried to set more than one MMD-Value in my WebPart Options but it is only taking one value. Below is my code with the property `IsMulti=true`.

Is there anything more I have to do, to get a Multi value Tax Control?

Thanks and Kind regards

Daniel

```
rel3DeptsTaxCtrl = new TaxonomyWebTaggingControl();
rel3DeptsTaxCtrl.ID = "rel3DeptsTaxCtrl";
rel3DeptsTaxCtrl.SspId.Add(termStore.Id);
rel3DeptsTaxCtrl.TermSetId.Add(productsTermSet.Id);
rel3DeptsTaxCtrl.IsAddTerms = false;
rel3DeptsTaxCtrl.AllowFillIn = false;
respDeptTaxCtrl.IsMulti = true;
respDeptTaxCtrl.IsUseCommaAsDelimiter = true;
rel3DeptsTaxCtrl.Text = webpart._Relevanz3;
toolPartPanel.Controls.Add(rel3DeptsTaxCtrl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in your code sample you have 2 controls - `rel3DeptsTaxCtrl` and `respDeptTaxCtrl`. The control that is added to the tool part panel is not set to allow multiple values.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much. I haven´t seen that after my c&p :(